How to correctly add_overall and add_ci for continuos varibales in tbl_summary?
Hy everyone, i need to make a table with add_overall and add_ci.
At the start i was using the following code:
iris %>% 
tbl_summary(by = Species,
            type = all_continuous() ~ "continuous2",
            statistic = all_continuous() ~ c(
              "{mean}+-{sd}",
              "{median} ({p25} - {p75})",
              "{min} - {max}")) %>% 
  add_ci() %>% 
  add_overall(last=TRUE)

The result is not good because i need the CI provided for the overall too.

So i made a simple change in the code
iris %>% 
  tbl_summary(by = Species,
              type = all_continuous() ~ "continuous2",
              statistic = all_continuous() ~ c(
                "{mean}+-{sd}",
                "{median} ({p25} - {p75})",
                "{min} - {max}")) %>% 
  add_overall(last=TRUE) %>% 
  add_ci()

Which provide me the following error message:
Error in `map()`:
ℹ In index: 1.
Caused by error in `dplyr::relocate()`:
ℹ In argument: `all_of(stat_cols_in_order)`.
Caused by error in `all_of()`:
! Can't subset elements that don't exist.
✖ Element `ci_stat_0` doesn't exist.
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.

How can i solve this? When i use only cathegorical variables the same code runs.

You can use tbl_merge() where you have one table that is stratified by species and one table that is not. Then you merge them together like so:
tbl_merge(list(iris %>% 
  tbl_summary(by = Species,
              type = all_continuous() ~ "continuous2",
              statistic = all_continuous() ~ c(
                "{mean}+-{sd}",
                "{median} ({p25} - {p75})",
                "{min} - {max}")
              ) %>% 
  add_ci(),
  iris %>% 
  tbl_summary(
              type = all_continuous() ~ "continuous2",
              statistic = all_continuous() ~ c(
                "{mean}+-{sd}",
                "{median} ({p25} - {p75})",
                "{min} - {max}")
  ) %>% 
    add_ci()), tab_spanner = c("Species","Overall"))
  

